# imprimir objetos PHP en AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, json

Tengo una clase en PHP en donde genero datos en JSON mediante funciones.
Al finalizar imprimo los datos en consola mediante objetos.. y hasta ahí todo bien...

```
class Grafica{

 public function subcategoria(){

     //codigo
     print json_encode($datos, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

 }


 public function prioridad(){

     // Codigo
     print json_encode($datos, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

 }
}

$sub = new Grafica();
$sub -> subcategoria();

$prio = new Grafica();
$prio -> prioridad();
```

Al querer imprimir los datos mediante AJAX, tengo el siguiente código:

```
$.getJSON("../../grafica.php", function(json) {
    options.series = json;
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

Al tener un objeto me grafica los datos sin ningún problema, el detalle va cuando tengo 2 objetos, se tendría que pasar como parámetro el objeto a imprimir, pero no logro entender cómo.
Alguna sugerencia que me puedan dar!!
Gracias!

Comment: No se entiende muy bien. ¿Quieres saber cómo imprimir más de un objeto o quieres saber cómo evitar que pase más de un objeto?

Comment: Imprimir más de un objeto.

Comment: Se supone que en ese caso `json` sería un array de objetos, entonces podrías leerlo así: `$.each( json, function( index, obj ){
    console.log(obj.series);
});`

Answer (score 0):

La clase Grafica está imprimiendo dos objetos JSON seguidos.

```
{datos}{datos}
```

getJSON no sabe que hacer con esa estructura.

Tienes que hacer que la clase Grafica imprima un array de JSONs

```
[{datos},{datos}]
```

O que imprima un JSON anidado.

```
{"subcategoria": {datos}, "prioridad": {datos}}
```

En el primer caso, al recibirlo, lo parseas a json y te devuelve un array de estos.

En el segundo caso, al recibirlo, lo parseas a json y al llamar a cada valor (subcategoria y prioridad), te devuelve el json correspondiente.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que crear un objeto json con los campos `subcategoría` y `prioridad` para `$.getJSON` pueda trabajar de manera correcta.

Así debería estar tu código PHP:

```php
class Grafica{

 public function subcategoria(){

     //codigo
     return $datos;

 }


 public function prioridad(){

     // Codigo
     return $datos;

 }
}

$sub = new Grafica();
$subCat = $sub->subcategoria();
$prioridad = $sub->prioridad();
$arr = [
    'subcategoria' => $subCat,
    'prioridad' => $prioridad
];
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```